# How to solve authentication failure with CNAME in url

Tags: kerberos, ntlm, cname

We have a web application written using Liferay 6.2 and deployed on tomcat server. Application is accessed using Integrated Windows Authentication. Everything works fine if hostname is directly used to in url to access.

To hide the actual hostname, a CNAME record was created. When that is used to access, users get repeated prompts for credentials and authentication is rejected despite entering correct credentials.

We tried creating SPN for CNAME using the command `setspn -a "HTTP/<<friendly name>>"`. Since connection is made on standard port 443 using HTTPS, no port number was specified when creating SPN. However, repeated authentication prompts still continue to appear. The application runs using a service account. Including the service account when creating SPN could be an option. Please share if there are any suggestions on what else could be tried.

Answer (score 1):

What does "everything works fine" mean? Are you getting prompted and when you enter creds it works correctly, or it does SSO and logs you in without a prompt?

The fact that you're getting prompted is because a) the new cname isn't considered to be in the intranet/trusted internet zone. See Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet/Trusted Sites > Sites. Or b) the requested ticket sent to the server failed.

Also usually you don't register the cname as an SPN. You register the A record the cname is pointing to as the SPN. My guess is this is causing the failure. The SPN is getting registered to the wrong service account so the KDC is using the wrong service account key.

Comment: With hostname in url, prompt comes once for the first attempt and AuthN goes through fine with correct credentials. I added the url with CNAME to Trusted Sites and it worked. SPN with CNAME was deleted after this. Will wait for some time and let other users validate it. Thanks.